# VBA Code to end macro at a time

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking around for a while trying to find a way to just force the macro to stop running at 1:15 pm. I have found things that will close the workbook at a certain time but nothing that will keep the workbook open and just stop the macro. I believe it has to do with the `Application.OnTime "13:15:00"` feature but I am not sure how to get it to stop the macro at the 1:15 pm.

This is what keeps my excel workbook running:
First when I open the workbook, this kicks in:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Time > TimeSerial(6, 45, 0) Then
    Call TimeStamp
    Else
    Application.Wait "06:45:00"
    Call TimeStamp
End Sub
```

That will then start the TimeStamp Macro which is ran every 15 minutes using these global variables and coding:

```
Option Explicit
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 900 ' 15 minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "TimeStamp"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True
```

After this section is my TimeStamp Macro which ends with: `Call StartTimer` to schedule the next run time 15 minutes from the current time.

Comment: Try playing around with `Application.OnTime TimeValue("13:15:00"), "MyMacro"`

Comment: You'll need a new global variable (Boolean) and set your initial function to execute only if this new variable is True. Now create new function called "StopMacro1()" that changes the global variable to False. use `Application.OnTime` to call this new function at 1:15 Pm

Comment: What is keeping the macro running?  Might help to show your existing code (or at least the relevant parts)

Comment: @TimWilliams Just added that part.

Comment: @Paulbica let me try that when I have a second here and I will let you know how that worked out.

Comment: `Time < TimeSerial(13,15,0)` will be True before 1:15 pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will stop scheduling the next run once it's later than 1:15pm

```
If Time < TimeSerial(13,15,0) Then

    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
        Schedule:=True

End If
```